# No Sound from Sound Blaster ZxR on Fresh LTS 18.04 Dual Boot Install

Tags: sound, soundcard

Long-time Winblows user, noob to the Wonderful World of Linux/Debian, here! I hope you all are having a great week so far! I'm a bit of a techie, though no formal PC experience, other than personal use. But, I'm an avid hobbyist now seeking to pursue a career in IT. Been messing around with Linux servers for a little while for web hosting and other use (I have an unmanaged VPS account which has been some GREAT experience). Having always respected Linux, I'm now making the switch.

I have a pretty massive custom build that's only as year or 2 old, speced out as follows:

> ASUS Maximus VIII Extreme Assembly MoBo
>
> 64 GB Corsair Vengeance @ 3000MHz
>
> 960 EVO m.2 (that Ubuntu's running on right now)
>
> More TB's of storage than I can remember right now. In the area of 9-10, before the 20 TB USB Raid 10 array, configured to about 10TB for redundancy.
>
> Zotac GTX1080 Arctic Storm GPU
>
> i7 6700K
>
> 64 GB of Corsair Vengeance Ram at 3000MHz

I'm pretty technical, despite being a former Master Auto Tech, so I really enjoy finding the fix on my own. I already went through the nightmare of trying to figure out why I kept having SATA errors while trying to get the dual boot install to go through. I found out about the issue with the ASM1061 controller. I was using all my SATA ports and now can't use my BluRay drive until I look for that fix (if any), but at least so far, everything else is great, with the hiccup that's bringing me here now. I have 4 monitors hooked up and can get sound from the 3 linked via HDMI, but I'm not getting any sound from any programs out of any of my  sound card outputs, most preferably the optical S/PDIF out feeding the Logitech 5.1 system! I've looked all around and basically everything I find says that it should just work. I can select the different outputs but can't seem to get sound from the card. I haven't yet tried the MoBo output(s), but I see all mic inputs do work, and I have an analog mic attached to the MoBo mic in. I'm actually now thinking of trying to swap the optical cable to the MoBo S/PDIF out for further diag when I'm finished with this post.

This one really has me STUMPED! Any and all help you can provide would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: ***Update***

I confirmed I DO have sound output from the optical out of the MoBo. This is definitely isolated to the sound card, which DOES work in Winblows.

Answer (score 1):

could be a driver issue but I had this on my dell, for me it turned out to be audio mixer levels - which I think it mutes when you plug in speakers.

i ran `alsamixer` from terminal and un-muted channels and it worked (mine was a fresh install and others had same issue on forums)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't know about that mixer c/p. I went into it and raised all the volumes, but still no go. I was thinking in the lines of a driver issue. Maybe I'll try contacting Creative to see if they have a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie subscriber, so I don't have 50x access for subscribe. And my english is very bad :-)  And long time ago I wasn't in Linux.

**I have Creative Sound Blaster Z in kernel 4.18.**

I see changelogs later and...

```
https://kernelnewbies.org/FindPage?action=fullsearch&advancedsearch=1&and_terms=ca0132&or_terms=&not_terms=&mtime=&categories=&language=&mimetype=


Initial support in HDA codec is in Linux 3.1.

In Linux 4.2 is supported Alienware SB chip .
```

And finally! Our results!
kernel 4.18 changes to hda/ca0132

```
Add DSP Volume set and New mixers for SBZ + R3Di
Add new control changes for SBZ + R3Di
Add pincfg for SBZ + R3Di, add fp hp auto-detect
```

kernel 4.19 changes to hda/ca0132

```
hda/ca0132: Adds support for the Recon3D PCI-E card
```

In log 4.18:

```
    dmesg | grep ca0132
[   11.315427] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D1: autoconfig for Sound Blaster Z: line_outs=3 (0xb/0x11/0x10/0x0/0x0) type:line
[   11.315428] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D1:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   11.315430] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D1:    hp_outs=1 (0xf/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   11.315430] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D1:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   11.315431] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D1:    dig-out=0xc/0xd
[   11.315432] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D1:    inputs:
[   11.315433] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D1:      Mic=0x12
[   11.315434] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D1:      Line=0x13
[   11.315435] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D1:    dig-in=0xe
[   12.024326] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC1D1: ca0132 DSP downloaded and running

dmesg | grep HDA
[   12.807269] input: HDA Creative Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/sound/card1/input10
[   12.807308] input: HDA Creative Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/sound/card1/input11
[   12.807339] input: HDA Creative Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/sound/card1/input12
[   12.807369] input: HDA Creative Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/sound/card1/input13
```

No sound. But all programs pavucontrol, recognize sound card and I see barmeters/peakbars if sound play. But in this programs nothing help...

**But in ALSAMIXER a change one value only. Output Select to Headphones.** And I have sound now!
This wasn't function in others sound programs.
No need more patching kernel or something...
With new kernels this is will great! I'm coming to new kernel. :-)
GL
Bye. Rovano